# install helm chart package without public container registry (offline,locally)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My problem is when i want to install a package in kubernetes cluster with helm chart, for example install gitlab with helm, during installation there is need to download docker image from a public registry and i don't access internet and i ran nexus repository in my local environment but in helm chart i can't set my local nexus docker image repository  as a registry to helm and helm try to download docker image from internet not my local repository.

how can i set my local nexus repository as a primary docker registry for helm chart?

in helm chart this is difficult to change instruction of a ready to use helm chart, for example gitlab helm chart, and you can only download docker images independently and if **PullPolicyImage** set to **IfNotPresent** image does not download again.

you can change helm chart ready to use repo, to download images from you local repo with adding your **local_registryIP:Port** in front of a docker image address. but as i said this difficult for large helm chart like gitlab.

Comment: The Helm chart needs some mechanism to change the registry, often a `.Values.registry` setting, but this is purely conventional and needs to be implemented in each chart.  Do you have an existing chart that you authored that you're trying to update?

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes i want to install git lab with helm and i can't find any thing about that problem.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a programming-related problem.  You might find [devops.se] or [sf] a better place to ask.

Comment: yes you right, i ask this question in server fault. thanks